# Will this null comparison always produce same result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am testing if a varchar field is not null or empty.  Performing the test using `[field] <>''` seems to work fine including if the value is `NULL`.

But are there scenarios where this may not work as expected, eg different collation or ANSI NULL settings?

Would I be safer to use `[field] IS NOT NULL AND [field]<>''` ?

Comment: Yes, this or ISNULL([field],'') <> ''

Comment: isnull(field, '') <> ''

Comment: It's always good practice to make your query/application/whatever safe from every example of "dirty data".

Comment: Storing empty strings is bad practice.  It's best to use a check constraint to prevent empty strings entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There really is no need for an inequality check here at all (remember that <> is nonSARGable). Since you want the rows that are NOT NULL and not an empty string you can simplify this and make your predicates SARGable.

```
[field] > ''
```

Comment: +1 this.  By definition, the [field] must be a non-empty string.  This answer will also use indexes and will offer better performance over any of the other answers posted here.

Comment: Excellent !  I'm accepting this as the answer because it's concise and neat, will always produce desired result, and you've taught me a new word that I will try to use in everyday conversation!

Comment: For some more details on SARGability...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable There are plenty of other more in depth resources of course.

Comment: I did not know this and made a test table just to check it because i could not believe it at first. It actually works so I learned something again today

Comment: @GuidoG it works because NULL is neither <, > or = to anything so it will always be excluded. And the > '' will obviously eliminate the empty string. Just a different way to look at how NULL and equality works. ;)

Comment: One possible exception might be  `char(0) > ''` char(0) has a length and can be stored but is technically a null char

Comment: @userSteve char(0) is not a valid datatype in t-sql. Try it. And anybody who defined a column like that should be slapped for being so absurd.

Comment: @SeanLange  Very rare and stupid, but I have seen the null char being used as control codes within data.   Try this example:  

`declare @t table (String varchar(max),Val varchar(max));
insert into @t (String,Val) values ('a','a');
insert into @t (String,Val) values ('empty','');
insert into @t (String,Val) values ('null',null);
insert into @t (String,Val) values ('char(0)',char(0));
select String,Val,len(Val) as Size from @t;`

Comment: '' compares as equal to a single space ' ', and _after_ the earlier characters.  Not just char(0), but also CR and LF.  So a value like `char(10) + 'hello'` will sort _before_ ''.

Comment: I see...I thought you meant using a datatype of char(0) not the char function. And try your code above. CHAR(0) is essentially an empty string which will still be excluded.

Comment: I would think most of the time a string that contains any of those single characters that are non-printable would want to be excluded anyway as those are essentially non-values often entered by content editors.

Comment: Carriage Return, Line Feed, and Tab are all printable, and sort before Space, and therefore before an empty string.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft   I think you're partially right.  `char(32)>''` is `false`, implying there is no value when there is.  However I couldn't find the same effect for other non-printable chars

Comment: Space and Empty String are not the same string, but they are equal, according to the sort order. In SQL Server string comparisons ignore trailing spaces.  So `select 1 where  'hello' = 'hello '` returns 1.  Similarly '' and ' ' are equal in the sort order, eg `select 1 where  '' = ' '`.  And since they are equal, neither can sort before the other.

Comment: TLDR; This answer works for all situations except where the value is a single character `ASCII 0` (null char) or `ASCII 32` (space).    Which admittedly would be very unusual and likely indicate missing real-world data anyway, although technically is still a stored value.
@SeanLange do you agree?

Comment: @userSteve I think that is pretty much what I was trying to say. :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be safer to use the official syntax 'IS NULL' OR 'IS NOT NULL'

Answer (score 0):

You can check below script:

`ISNULL([field], '') <> ''`

Answer (score 0):

for a varchar field the check

```
[field] IS NOT NULL AND [field]<>''
```

can be done shorter like this

```
ISNULL([field], '') <> ''
```

They do exact the same thing

But as Pred mentioned in his comment, it could have negative impact on performance so the answer of Sean is better

Comment: Can be done with the shorter syntax, but check the execution plans especially if you have an index on the field